# What is Xcode x or iOS and OS x shall I use?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

I made an application on my iPhone 4 and it works fine, then I plugged in iPhone 6 and it did an error.

I'm using something simple:

- Link to a webpage.
- Link to Instagram application, if I don't have the Instagram application in my iPhone, it'll open it on Safari.
- Link to facebook application, if I don't have the facebook application in my iPhone, it'll open it on Safari.
- Link to youtube application, if I don't have the youtube application in my iPhone, it'll open it on Safari.
- Maps, first one is the location to one place only (48.827672, 2.382110), second one is my GPS to a specified location (48.827672, 2.382110).
- Email.

That's it, simple stuff, now I would like what Xcode shall I use or what iOS should I use to work with 'all' iPhone, like WhatsApp :)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the latest version of Xcode, [Xcode 7](http://developer.apple.com/xcode/).

Comment: Thank you, I'll download it :)